# How do i add everytime a click on my pane a different Figure?

Tags: javafx

I need to add to my pane a Square, A Circle and a rectangle in this order everytime i click, so at the firs click i will add the square , at the second one the circle, the third one the rectangle and the fourth one again the square and so on.

```
  r1.setOnMouseClicked((T) -> {
 if (T.getClickCount() == 1 || (T.getClickCount()%2 != 0 && T.getClickCount() % 3 != 0))
             {
                 Rectangle r = new Rectangle(T.getSceneX(), T.getSceneY(), 50, 50);
                 root.getChildren().add(r);
             }
         else if (T.getClickCount()%2 == 0 && T.getClickCount() % 3 != 0) {

             Circle c1 = new Circle(T.getSceneX(), T.getSceneY(), 50);
             root.getChildren().add(c1);

        }
          else if (T.getClickCount()%2 != 0 && T.getClickCount() % 3 == 0) {

             Rectangle r3  = new Rectangle(T.getSceneX(), T.getSceneY(), 40, 70);
             root.getChildren().add(r3); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show ?

Comment: actually no, its a part of a project and i really have no ideas how to do it, i tried using GetClickCount() but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: i just added the code i tried.

Comment: Of course, getClickCount return the number of click you've done (fast), when you stop clicking the counter is reset to 0

Comment: Oh, ok , so how can i get the numbers of total clicks, is there any method?

Comment: I used a counter variable bellow, maybe there is another solution, I've never used JavaFX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this example using your above code:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Test1 extends Application{
    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        canvas.setPrefSize(350,250);
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked((t) -> {
            count ++;
            System.out.println("".format("%s %s %s", count, t.getSceneX(), t.getSceneY()));
            if (count == 1 || (count%2 != 0 && count % 3 != 0))
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.RED);
                r.relocate(t.getSceneX(),t.getSceneY());
                canvas.getChildren().add(r);
            }
            else if (count%2 == 0 && count % 3 != 0) {

                Circle c1 = new Circle(50,Color.GREEN);
                c1.relocate(t.getSceneX(), t.getSceneY());
                canvas.getChildren().add(c1);

            }
            else if (count%2 != 0 && count % 3 == 0) {

                Rectangle r3  = new Rectangle(40, 70, Color.PINK);
                r3.relocate(t.getSceneX(), t.getSceneY());
                canvas.getChildren().add(r3); 
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas);
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
     }
 }
```